# Raspberry Pi running remote SSH command to display GUI image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have a ubuntu machine that has a shell script on it. When I SSH into this machine from my Windows box, I can run "**export DISPLAY=:0**" and then run the script "**/home/enter.sh**" and the image displays properly on the Ubuntu machine.

However, when I try to run a remote SSH command from a raspberry Pi, "**ssh root@192.168.1.35 /home/enter.sh**", after exporting the display, I still receive the error "**display-im6.q16: unable to open X server `' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/432**"

Comment: Do you run `export DISPLAY=:0` after connecting interactively in the first case? And before connecting non-interactively (`ssh root@… /home/enter.sh`) in the second case?

Comment: yes, both instances I ran the command 'export DISPLAY=:0' followed by calling the script.

Comment: I also just validated that I can ssh from the rPi in interactive mode, export the display and run the script just fine.  Again it fails in non-interactive mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run this on the Pi:

```sh
# shell on Pi
export DISPLAY=:0
ssh root@192.168.1.35 /home/enter.sh
```

you're running `export …` on the Pi. Then `ssh` inherits the variable from the shell but it doesn't push its environment to the server. It can set `DISPLAY` on the server but the variable won't have the value you set on the client (see `man 1 ssh`, ENVIRONMENT section).

But when you run this:

```sh
# connected to the server interactively
# interactive shell on the server
export DISPLAY=:0
/home/enter.sh
```

you're running `export …` on the server. Then `enter.sh` inherits the exported variable from the interactive shell.

---

With `ssh` you can run more than one command. Like this:

```sh
# shell on Pi
ssh root@192.168.1.35 'export DISPLAY=:0; /home/enter.sh; another_command; yet_another'
```

This way `export …` is run on the server. The variable will matter for `enter.sh`, `another_command` and `yet_another`.

Or you can set the variable for `enter.sh` only. If the script was local, it would be like:

```
DISPLAY=:0 /home/enter.sh
```

(note the lack of semicolon). With `ssh` it will be:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.35 'DISPLAY=:0 /home/enter.sh'
```

In this case if you choose to add more commands then `DISPLAY=:0` will not affect them.